# cannot find symbol in java method

Tags: java, methods, calculator

cal.java

```
package calculator;
class Cal
{
    public int add(int num1,int num2)
    {
        return num1+num2;
    }
    public int mul(int num1,int num2)
    {
        return num1*num2;
    }
    public int sub(int num1,int num2)
    {
        return num1-num2;
    }
    public int div(int num1,int num2)
    {
        return num1/num2;
    }

}
```

Final.java

```
import calculator.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Final
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What operation would you like to perform? press 1 for add \n press 2 for sub \n press 3 for mul \n press 4 for divide\n");
        Integer s=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the first number?");
        Integer n1=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the second number you want to enter?");
        Integer n2=in.nextInt();
        Cal obj=new Cal();
        switch(s)
        {
            case 1:
            System.out.println(obj.add(n1+n2));
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println(obj.sub(n1-n2));
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println(obj.mul(n1*n2));
            break;
            case 4:
            System.out.println(obj.div(n1/n2));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a calculator using java packages and i keep getting these error

```
**calculator\\Final.java:14: error: cannot find symbol**
Cal obj=new Cal();
^
symbol:   class Cal
location: class Final
calculator\\Final.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
Cal obj=new Cal();
^
symbol:   class Cal
location: class Final
2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

`class Cal` has no visibility modifier (`public`, `private`, or `protected`), so it's defaulting to the seldom-used package-private visibility, which means it can only be seen in the current package and nowhere else. Declare it as

```
public class Cal { ... }
```

and you'll be able to see it.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am getting these errors can you help me? ->>> calculator\Final.java:18: error: method add in class Calculator cannot be applied to given types;
            System.out.println(obj.add(n1+n2));
                                  ^
  required: int,int
  found:    int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
calculator\Final.java:21: error: method sub in class Calculator cannot be applied to given types;
            System.out.println(obj.sub(n1-n2));
                                  ^
  required: int,int
  found:    int

Comment: Look at the argument list that you're passing to the functions and look at the function declarations. You should be passing as many arguments as the function expects, no more and no less.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again i appreciate it so much. Inn the file i created the package i passed put two arguments public int add(int num1,int num2) . In the one i am trying to call the package from "final.java" i have passed two too. System.out.println(obj.add(n1+n2)) or is this the wrong way?

Comment: `n1+n2` is one argument. In Java, we separate arguments with commas. Consider `obj.add(n1, n2)` (and the same for the other calls, of course).